# "Liferay.Language.get" javascript call returns key instead of value

Tags: javascript, liferay-6

In our portlet, we are trying to access the language properties in our javascript files using `Liferay.Language.get("key")`.

But `Liferay.Language.get("key")` returns the key instead of the associated value.

Did any one face similar issue?

We are using Liferay 6.1 EE. And have already seen the [LPS-16513](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-16513)

The strangest part is it works on our local boxes but fails on server.

Any pointers other than using ext?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess based on the information you give is that you're asking for a key that does not have a translation associated with it - for these returning the key is the default behaviour.

But then, this question is quite old, you might have already solved it. (If so, please let us know how - if you can remember the cause)

Answer (score 1):

I also can't get it to retrieve a value for a valid key that's specified in a resource bundle in a portlet itself. It will retrieve values for keys in the default Liferay language bundles though. One hack is to add a **liferay-hook.xml** to your portlet and add something like the following to it:

```
<language-properties>Language.properties</language-properties>
```

When I do this it will now retrieve my custom/additional keys. The side effect is that your keys will also be available globally in Liferay.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work for portlet level language.pro.

I have same problem with 6.2 EE too, as an alternative I went for below solution.

```
  <script>
  var test = "<liferay-ui:message key='test'/>";
  console.log("This is working :: "+test)
  </script>
```

Thank,
Sagar Vyas

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the desired value with the following snippet:

```
var value='<%=LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "key") %>';
```